# Ionic slide box set height as percentage not working with ios

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to set the `ion-slide-box` to a fix height with percentage as follow. However, when i try to do ionic serve the height in percentage not showing in ios but only in android.

```
.slider {
  height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code:

```
height: 50vh;
```

It works on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I accomplished what you're asking that should work in all platforms:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header-flex {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider-flex">
    <ion-slides>
      <ion-slide-page>
        <div class="box blue">
          <h1>BLUE</h1>
        </div>
      </ion-slide-page>
      <ion-slide-page>
        <div class="box yellow">
          <h1>YELLOW</h1>
        </div>
      </ion-slide-page>
      <ion-slide-page>
        <div class="box pink">
          <h1>PINK</h1>
        </div>
      </ion-slide-page>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
</div>
```